# set initial value of an angularjs select from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I have 2 select tag inputs for country and state. They currently work with initial string values set by variables in an angular controller. I want to get those 2 variables from a service that has W3C geocoding and google-map address_components and set the HTML template with them on page load.

I have many problems, but first I want a hard coded object in a service to update the controller, which in turn updates the HTML. I've spent a lot of time on that data transfer and I can't get it. Then I'll change the hard coded object to feed it location data from google-map, which I've done before.

The HTML is:

```
<select id="country"data-ngmodel="cntrl.input.countrySelected"                  
    data-ng-options="country.code as country.text group by country.continent for country in cntrl.input.countries" >
</select> //cntrl.input.countries is set from a factory via the controller
<select id="state" data-ng-model="cntrl.input.stateSelected"                            
    data-ng-options="state.code as (state.code + ' - ' + state.text) for state in cntrl.input.state" >
</select> //cntrl.input.state is set from a factory via the controller
```

I'm using controller as, and the relevant controller code is:

```
//cntrl.input.countrySelected = "US"; //hard coded works
//cntrl.input.stateSelected = "NY"; //hard coded works
//Edited, though still not working. Now just
cntrl.input.countrySelected = getUserGeolocateService.getUserLocation();
//cntrl.input.countrySelected = function initialCountry() {
//getUserGeolocateService.getUserLocation() //getUserLocation from getUserGeolocateService in getUserGeolocate.service.js
//.then( function( locationName4 ) {
    //return locationName4[country]; //object containing country and state
//});       
//}
```

I can't get this working, so I have not written anything to set the initial state variable. It would be the same format as a working country instruction.

I tried to make the service code like another method/function that works to provide different location data. I'm new to both services and promises. Relevant code for the angular service is:

```
(function() { "use strict";
angular.module( "residenceApp" ).service( "getUserGeolocateService", function( $http, $q, uiGmapGoogleMapApi ) {
    this.getUserLocation = function(){
        var countryCode, stateCode, county, location4;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        location4 = {};
        location4 = { "country": "US", "state": "NY"};
        deferred.resolve( location4 );
        console.log("country & state:" + locationName4); //does not fire
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

This code makes the select tag active - clicking the down arrow opens a dropdown which can be selected. The initial select tag is blank and countrySelected is not set to anything. The hard coded object, locationName4 should set one select to United States and the other to New York, if the service and the controller functions were correct. The ng-options code takes a country code and uses it to display text for the country name.

Comment: your initialCountry function does nothing - it does not change any variables and does not haave any return statement

Comment: Try adding `track by country.code` (or `track by state.code`) to `data-ng-options`.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, Yes it does not set an initial variable - that is the problem. It does have a return statement - look again. What should I do to make these components work?

Comment: @HankScorpio I put track by in front of the existing statement, i.e.,  "track by country.code as . . . " and it broke the select. Nothing appears. Thanks though for something new to try.

Comment: Mike, return is in inner function, so your function returns nothing.

Comment: I have changed the controller statement to  cntrl.input.countrySelected = getUserGeolocateService.getUserLocation[country];   It triggers the service and I see logs. No errors are in the Console. The select box appears, but it is blank - not set to anything. When clicked it operates. Slight progress, but not working. Petr, thanks for your comment. It led to the complete re-write. Still no cigar for me.

Comment: The angular service returns something. When I put a console.log just before getUserGeolocateService.getUserLocation(country);  I see the following log - {"$$state":{"status":1,"value":{"country":"US","state":"NY"}}} What does that mean? How do I get "US" and "NY" out of that mess? Or do I need to change something in the service function?

Comment: My latest version of the controller function is: cntrl.input.countrySelected = function initialCountry( getUserGeolocateService ){return getUserLocation[country];} It does not have Console errors and does not set an initial value for countrySelected. I've tried a lot of things and have hit a wall.

Answer (score -1):

OK, theory says its possible to do anything in a service that you can do in a factory. But for me, a service is not worth the trouble when it returns {"$$state":{"status":1,"value":{"country":"US","state":"NY"}}}, and 15 people look at this with no working response. I changed the module to a factory, which returns a plain JS object. The factory code is:

```
function getUserGeolocateFactory(){
var location4;
return { getCountryState: function() {
    location4 = { "country": "US", "state": "NY"}; //TEST: object
    return location4;       
    }
  }
}
```

The controller code is:

```
cntrl.input.countrySelected = initialCountry();
function initialCountry(){
    var name4=getUserGeolocateFactory.getCountryState();
    return name4.country;
};
```

Quick and straightforward. The select tag gets an initialized value. Done.